# RF for Data Transmit and Receicve for Beginners

Tags: digital-communications

Is there any good matrial avialable for data specific DSP? I have gone through some great DSP intros for beginners in python but all of them revolve around the characteristics of audio signal

Comment: Yes. Basically all my education in communications engineering was pure DSP or closely related to it. And that took a very solid part of my whole EE studies. So, I can point you to racks of books in my uni library – but I'm not sure that would help you! What's your background, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would consider this a feature, not a "bug", because the proximity with audio means that you can immediately test what you learn on your computer with relatively inexpensive equipment. I feel lucky to know what does a moving average / low pass filter sounds like. You develop a familiarity with the subject that is not possible with other subjects. It is a permeating paradigm too, see for example what is mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density) at "...statisticians study the variance of a function..."

Comment: my background is python and java and have worked with SS7 packets stored sequentially in a file. Now I am up against SDR-RTL, and would like to explore and learn how to read/transmit data on RF. Not really interested in freshman level theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible combination is a copy of [Digital Communications](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Communications-John-Proakis/dp/0072957166) by Proakis & Salehi along with [GNU Radio](https://www.gnuradio.org/blog/the-limesdr-project/).

With SDR, you actually create / process the signals that carry your data over the RF medium.

Therefore, to an extent, "freshman level theory" is all you are stuck with if you have to write an end-to-end SDR system.

But, you could keep the book (or, a book) as a reference for points you don't understand when going through something like [GNU Radio's PSK Demodulation](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation) resources for example.

I am not sure what your expectation is from SDR, but taking the comment (about SS7) as a starting point, it's not like the SDR has an API which you use to simply "send data". Although, I am sure that [you could add that layer too once you have your basic DSP dataflow set up](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python).

The beauty of SDR is that you take full control of every building block from transmission to reception. So, there is nothing stopping you from writing a [Phase Locked Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) (which you are going to need) from first principles or use [one of the existing ones](https://gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1analog_1_1pll__refout__cc.html#details) (or [here](https://gnuradio.org/doc/sphinx/analog_blocks.html#gnuradio.analog.pll_refout_cc)).

But you still have to have some awareness of what is the "loop bandwidth" for example, in the case of the PLL.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, if you felt that this response was helpful please consider upvoting and / or accepting it as an answer. This will stop it from circulating in the list as "un-answered". All the best. @user482963